# Error in a simple history bash script execution in a Docker container with a "kathara Image"

Tags: linux, bash, docker, command

So i have this code that executes well in my machine

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o history
history -w "hist.txt"
```

but when i execute it in my docker container it fills the hist.txt file with :

```
history -w "hist.txt"
```

Plus whenever i do something like `history > hist.txt` in my script its always the same thing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did try this out and I find only 1 entry in the hist.txt. Can you share the Dockerfile and how you start the docker container?

Comment: i didnt use a Dockerfile , instead i use a container based on "kathara/quagga" image , to start the container i use the "kathara lstart" command but i also have started it manually using : docker run -it kathara/quagga bash  and the problem persists i think the problem is the kathara image no ?

Answer (score 0):

`history -w "hist.txt"` is the only command executed in that context, and therefore `history` contains only that -> it is found from "hist.txt".

That is probably because HISTFILE enviroment variable is not defined.

You can set it by adding line `HISTFILE=~/.bash_history` for example. This only helps, if there is some history in that file.

If you don't have preceding history in that Docker container, it is probably empty.

Related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script